# Computer doesn't start after i upgraded RAM. DDR3 RAM

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I have bought a new stick of RAM and I installed in my computer and after that it will not start.
The display remains black and shows nothing.
The new stick is working because I tried in another computer and worked fine.
I have the same stick of RAM in PC but with the new one, alone in PC it does not want to start.

My motherboard is ECS A780LM-M2
The new stick of RAM is KingMax 2GB DDR3 1333MHz CL9

What could be going wrong and how would i fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer doesn't start after installing new RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/438575/computer-doesnt-start-after-installing-new-ram)

Comment: I read the answers and I couldn't find the solution to my problem

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Your question has no details to help you with.

Comment: @Arjan well he added some now

Comment: You got the volts right http://www.kingmax.com/en-global/product/product/Model/DDR3_Desktop_memory_module     http://download.ecs.com.tw/dlfileecs/manual/mb/A780LM-M2/A780LM-M2%20_manual.pdf    1.8 volts.

Comment: Try other combinations. Try the new stick alone in the   machine. Maybe your motherboard needs RAM on its list of compatible RAM modules . http://www.ecs.com.tw/website2008/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=1277&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=24&LanID=0   scroll down, Click the Mrmory tab and a list appears.

Comment: Try other combinations. Try the new stick alone in the machine. Maybe your motherboard needs RAM on its list of compatible RAM modules . http://www.ecs.com.tw/website2008/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=1277&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=24&LanID=0 scroll down, Click the Memory tab and a list appears.   It lists 3 Kingmax modules that are 2GB. Is yours on the list?  If not then that may be the problem. If it is then I don't know, I can then only suggest calling/contacting ECS and Kingmax. I don't know if they would then say it's a motherboard issue or a RAM issue...

Comment: I guess if it's both a MBRD and RAM issue.. like an incompatibility.. the see it as a RAM issue 'cos that's cheaper.. And then look to buy RAM that should work.   If that RAM module is listed but doesn't work.. How about if you buy a RAM module identical to the one you already have

Comment: @barlop, do you really think this is different from the duplicate? If you have an answer that is not listed there, may I kindly suggest to add it there, for future visitors? A dupe is a dupe, I'd say.

Comment: @Arjan well, the other q is a bit clouded with the idea that the motherboard supports DDR2 and DDR3. One answer mentions DDR2 modules.  His Q  is just straight he has a motherboard with DDR3 and his RAM is DDR3

Comment: All too specific for my liking, @barlop (the other question as well), but of course my vote just counts as one. (As a future visitor I would not want to browse too many questions.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26488/discussion-between-barlop-and-arjan).

Comment: I do not have the reputation to participate in the chat. I have the same stick already installed on my motherboard and this new stick alone in my PC does not work. I tried to place it in both slots. Nothing. And i checked if is in the list and it is. Both sticks and i know for sure this new stick works because i tried it into a friend computer.

Comment: @barlop you say to change the volts of memory to 1.8v?

Comment: @loopByte No you can't change the voltage and you got the voltage right, perfectly matching voltage. You did well(maybe by luck) but it still didn't work.  You did everything perfectly, it's even in the list, and it still didn't work.  Don't say that the RAM is fine, it could be something weird about both RAM and MBRD that makes them not work together. What size is the previous stick you have in there? Is it 2GB as well?  So you're upgrading to 4GB with 2*2GB?  If so, you could look to get one identical model number to the other 2GB one. And call both the MBRD and RAM places cwhat they say.

Comment: @barlop Both sticks are 2 GB

Comment: @loopByte Is the original one a different make/model that is on the list?  or the same model?  What make/model number is the other one? (the 2GB one that works and has always worked in the machine)

Comment: @barlop On both sticks is written FLFE85F -(dash) and on the new one is 3AKQ9 and the old one is C8KL9. And i checked on the ECS site and none of those code can be found on the Memory page.

Comment: @loopByte So your RAM is not actually in the list, so it's not listed as compatible, neither is. The first one happened to work, though your motherboard manufacturer hadn't tested it(you now have but they haven't). The second one also isn't listed, meaning it hasn't been tested by your motherboard manufacturer, but it seems from your test that it doesn't work. Try getting one that is listed(as your motherboard manu tested to conclude that it works). Or perhaps one identical model to the one you had originally(as you tested that to conclude that it worked).

Comment: I will undelete my answer as I deleted it when you said the new module was  on the list. But now you have shown it isn't, neither is.

Comment: Try upgrading your BIOS to the latest version.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i did but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You got the volts right

http://www.kingmax.com/en-global/product/product/Model/DDR3_Desktop_memory_module
1.8V

http://download.ecs.com.tw/dlfileecs/manual/mb/A780LM-M2/A780LM-M2%20_manual.pdf
1.8 volts.

Maybe your motherboard needs RAM on its list of compatible RAM modules

http://www.ecs.com.tw/website2008/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=1277&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=24&LanID=0

scroll down, Click the Mrmory tab and a list appears.

Looking at your latest comments, neither module is on the list, the first works, the second doesn't. So get one that's on the list or identical to the first.

The list means the motherboard manufacturer has tested it and found that it works.  Or one identical to the original since you tested that one and found that it worked, and you'll be using it anyway in the upgrade from 2GB to 2GB via 2*2GB.

Comment: perhaps if you keep the original one(not listed) then if you're super unlucky maybe it's possible that the new module will work but not with the old one.   e.g. maybe they test very rigorously, and so your test of the original module wouldn't be as wide ranging as theirs amd there may be an issue in keeping it that's just a guess. I haven't really run into RAM compatibility issues.. But you can try it and see. If you want to be super safe and a bit wastful and get it sorted as fast as possible, you can buy 2 modules on the list and get rid of the current unlisted one.

Comment: but I think you can guess that the current working one will still work with a new that will work, and so get a module identical to it or listed.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess you are wright about the first stick. I thought i could do something to make it work but it seems I can't. I know i should vote for your answer but it seems i can't because i don't have the necessary reputation. Thank you again!

Comment: @loopByte well, you'll only have tested if my answer works when you get a new RAM stick

Comment: I think I can return the new stick of ram I bought and try to find one that matches the memory list on ECS web site

Comment: @loopByte sounds like a good plan.

Comment: I think it is. Thank you again for your time!